# Bold changed cells in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, eventtrigger

I would like to bold changed `DataGrid` cells when data source gets updated. I found that `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">` is the event I need. However I cannot get the `Storyboard` to work with the `FontWeight` property.

Here is what I am trying:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <Int32Animation Duration="00:00:05" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Int32)(DataGridCell.FontWeight)"  
                From="400" To="700" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Can someone please recommend how to get the above fixed or propose new smarter way of bolding changed cells in `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

I have a resource...

```
   <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="ElementStyle">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                   <Storyboard>
                      <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                          Duration="00:00:01"
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.FontWeight)">
                             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
                                KeyTime="00:00:00" 
                                Value="{x:Static FontWeights.Thin}" />
                             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
                                KeyTime="00:00:00.5" 
                                Value="{x:Static FontWeights.Heavy}" />
                             <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
                                KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                Value="{x:Static FontWeights.UltraBold}" />
                           </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                     </BeginStoryboard>                                
               </EventTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Assign this to relevant column,

```
  <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn 
        Binding="{Binding Quantity, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                          ElementStyle="{StaticResource ElementStyle}" />
```

**EDIT**

Bcause the code above makes the default values also Bold, we have another way to do this wherein ONLY the updates done by user would trigger boldness in the cell.

**Style**

```
  <Style TargetType="Controls:DataGridCell" 
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:DataGridCell}}" 
   x:Key="CellBoldStyle">
<Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Duration="00:00:01"                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty
                                    ="(TextBlock.FontWeight)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" 
                                Value="{x:Static FontWeights.Normal}" />
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                Value="{x:Static FontWeights.Bold}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

**Column**

```
  <Controls:DataGridTextColumn 
             Binding="{Binding Side, Mode=TwoWay, 
                               NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, 
                               NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
             CellStyle="{StaticResource CellBoldStyle}" />
```

**Limitations**

1. Virtualized cells would loose the bold highlighted effect when you scroll them out of your scroll view.
2. Even your TextBox shows Bold value . (I dont know if this is a limitation for you!)

Comment: Thanks man! I wish I could buy you a beer! :)
Do you know if there is a way to prevent running the TargetUpdated event on first time binding? My goal is to bold changed cells only when changed by the user after the initial loading of the app.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi,
I need something slightly different though.
In my case the user do not edit directly data in DataGrid. All changes are done by modifing the binded data programatically. The first sample that you show is working great, however on initial app loading all data gets bolded because target gets updated.
It is the TargetUpdated event that I need however I do not want to have it executed during the first binding while app is initializing.

Comment: Sadly simply using XAML based `TargetUpdated` wont help as that event will fire even when the target textblock is updated for the first time. I advise using attached behavior on the textblock to maintain a `flag` which can be made true ONLY after first `TragetUpdated` event handled against that `TextBlock` and the `Bold` animation runs henceforth only if the flag is true.