# How to Set bold text in changed cell datagrid wpf

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I am trying to acheive the following:

In a datagrid, when the user edits a cell, I need to make the text bold so that the user is aware of all the changes before committing it to database. I followed the post in this link -[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003902/bold-changed-cells-in-datagrid)

Problem is that the code works fine on DataGridTextColumn and it doesn't make any changes to the DataGridTemplateColumn. I am new to WPF and owndering if anyone can shed some light on the same and point me in the right way of doing it.

Thanks!